# Ionic's infinite scroll does not work properly - tied to window

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

The reason this isn't working is that when the user scrolls inside the div, nothing happens because it's not tied to the window. If the window is scrollable, infinite scrolling works perfectly, however, that's not what I need. The window that it's tied to is the scroll content class as a child of the ion-content tag. [ionicscroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/#input-properties) [resource](https://www.djamware.com/post/59b0ac0c80aca768e4d2b139/an-example-of-ionic-3-infinite-scroll-or-load-more)

HTML

```
<ion-content>

   <div class="wrapper">
       <ion-list>
               <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
                <ion-avatar item-start>
                 <img src="{{user.avatar}}">
                   </ion-avatar>
                  <h2>{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</h2>
                  </ion-item>
       </ion-list>

       <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinitetwo($event)" *ngIf="page < totalPage">
            <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data..."></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
       </ion-infinite-scroll>

   </div>
</ion-content
```

css

```
.scroll-content{ overflow: hidden }

.wrapper{height: calc(100vh - 299px);
                overflow-y:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change your

```
.wrapper {
    height: calc(100vh - 299px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

and try to do like this

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">{{i}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

and use for this one  [ion-infinite-scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/infinite-scroll)